# Dunford-Pettis theorem

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a bounded set in $L^{1}(\Omega)$. Then $\mathcal{F}$ has compact closure in the weak topology $\sigma(L^{1},L^{\infty})$ if and only if $\mathcal{F}$ is equi-integrable, that is,
\begin{cases}
\forall\epsilon>0\ \exists\delta>0\text{ such that}\\
\int_{A}|f|<\epsilon\ \forall A\subset\Omega,\text{measrable with }|A|<\delta,\ \forall f\in\mathcal{F}
\end{cases}
and
\begin{cases}
\forall\epsilon>0\ \exists\omega\subset\Omega,\text{ measurable with }|\omega|<\infty\text{ such that}\\
\int_{\Omega\backslash\omega}|f|<\epsilon\ \forall f\in\mathcal{F}.
\end{cases}
I would like to known if there is a difference between the bounded and unbounded case?

Lemma$^*$: Let $\mu_{d}$ be a (diffuse) measure in $\mathcal{M}_{d}(\Omega)$ and let $(v_{n})$ be a  sequence of functions in $W^{1,p}_{0}(\Omega)$, bounded in $L^{\infty}(\Omega)$, and converging to a function $v$ $\text{cap}_{p}-$q.e., then $(v_{n})$ converges to $v$ $\mu_{d}-$a.e. and 
$$\underset{n\rightarrow+\infty}{\operatorname{lim}}\int_{\Omega}v_{n}d\mu_{d}=\int_{\Omega}v d\mu_{d}.$$

Comment: What precisely do you mean by "bounded case" and by "unbounded case"? By the way, your second sentence is not correct.

Comment: I means that $\Omega$ is a bounded/unbounded subset, this is the definition given in [H. Brezis, Functional Analysis, Sobolev Spaces and Partial Differential Equations, Theorem 4.30 (Dunford–Pettis)]

Comment: In the ``unbounded'' case equiintegrability does not imply relative weak compactness; consider $f_n=$ the indicator function of $[n, n+1]$ in $L_1(\mathbb{R})$.